# Unable to set Authorization header for POST request to cross-domain

Tags: javascript, ajax, cors, authorization

I am having problem in sending Authorization header with POST request to api written in java, i am attaching my code with response and request headers.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://' + URLDomain + ':9090/path/to/api',
    type : 'POST',
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {             
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
       xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", encryptedText);
        },
    data: 'contentKey='+dataToSend,
     success: function(resp){
         console.log(resp);
     },
     error: function (err){
         console.log(err);
     }
});
```

Request Header: 
`Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Access-Control-Request-Headers:accept, access-control-allow-headers, access-control-allow-origin, authorization, content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method:POST
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Host:xxx.xxx.x.xx:9090
Origin:http://xxx.xxx.x.xxx
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:http://xxx.xxx.x.xxx/Project/path/Web/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36`

Response Header:
`Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Origin, Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers, authorization
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:POST, GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://xxx.xxx.x.xxx
Content-Length:0
Date:Wed, 27 Jul 2016 12:42:09 GMT
Set-Cookie:JSESSIONID=xk1ehwk88fn1tk8k6f81sojx;Path=/;HttpOnly`

i have followed following links :
[How to make GET CORS request with authorization header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25064158/how-to-make-get-cors-request-with-authorization-header)
and [How to add CORS support on the server side in Java with Jersey](http://www.codingpedia.org/ama/how-to-add-cors-support-on-the-server-side-in-java-with-jersey/)
But problem is still not solved.

Comment: Any one please help!! problem still not solved.