# Cross domain request with header authentication

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsonp

I need to send a `Get` request with cross domain origin with header authentication.

Its working fine in Chrome and Firefox, but I'm having issues in Safari and IE. Also in random cases it returns 401.

```
<script>
var url = 'username:password@anotherdomain.com';
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonpCallback: "callback",
    success: function(json) {
        alert(json);
    }
});
</script>
```

What would be the best option to solve this?

Comment: You get that "random" 401 with Firefox or Chrome or do you get it with Safari and IE? Is there a pattern to it? Like it is the url would be missing the appropriate protocol. You could use `console.log` rather than `alert` to get the contents of the JSON variable.

Comment: For Safari and IE, it is not even get executed and nothing show up in console. now i found that IE do not support user name and password in URL  https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/kb/834489 , so i am looking for any other way do have ajax call which support cross origin with header authentication

Comment: what version of the ie are you using?

Comment: I tried with all IE version IE9,IE10, EDGE

Comment: makes sure to use HTTPS for these type of interactions

Comment: You can refer this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9559947/cross-origin-authorization-header-with-jquery-ajax I hope it will helpful.

Comment: First of all this is NOT header authentication. But if you do need to send a HTTP header you may want to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5507234/how-to-use-basic-auth-with-jquery-and-ajax

Comment: An alternative will be to use a reverse proxy (e.g. Nginx) and avoid the cross-domain issue completely.

Comment: There is a server side solution for accepting all cross domain calls. So that you don't need to set any header for accepting cross domain calls on your request object. I can provide the solution if you are interested.

Comment: we ended up removing authentication from header and directly use server side validation. Thanks all for your feedback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I have understood the question correctly, you could use the beforeSend callback to add basic authentication on the request. This is irrelevant of jsonp or cross-origin though.

```
beforeSend: function (xhr) {
  xhr.setRequestHeader ("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password));
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rn9Lp304/

Comment: Kevin, Not sure if I have miss something when I tried with like this before. Its working fine  . Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For Internet Explorer `8 and 9` you need to use [**XDomainRequest Object**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288060(v=vs.85).aspx)

**Internet Explorer 10+** does the cross domain requests normally like all the other browsers.

As mentioned in the documentation you need to

- *create an object of the XDR* using `var xdr = new XDomainRequest();`
- *open the connection using the get method* using `xdr.open("get", "username:password@anotherdomain.com");`
- *send the data back to the server* using `xdr.send();`

The complete code reference can be shown as on [**this thread**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11267937/6606831) by  [@Mark Pieszak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1492009/mark-pieszak)

as a workaround to set the `username` and the `password` in the internet explorer you can set the following

> `DWORD` for `iexplore.exe` to `0` in: `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_HTTP_USERNAME_PASSWORD_DISABLE]`.

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend you to try two things:

In ajaxSetup, do this:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    ....,
    xhrFields: {
       withCredentials: true
    },
    crossDomain: true,
    ....
});
```

In your ajax requests, set the full url like so, in addition to the credentials flag.

```
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://not-example.com'
'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true'
```

For servers with authentication, these browsers do not allow "*" in this header. The Access-Control-Allow-Origin header must contain the value of the Origin header passed by the client.

Answer (score -3):

use getJSON

```
$.getJSON("url",function (data) {/*code here*/});
```

Comment: $.getJSON() is a shorthand for the $.ajax() jQuery method, were it to solve the issue an explanation would still be required as to why it solves it