# API calls with JWT authentication returns 401

Tags: angular, jwt, webapi, http-status-code-401, .net-6.0

I have a .NET 6 Web API application that uses JWT authentication. The front end is an angular application. When I make an API call with the bearer token in the header, it returns the 401 error code. But with the same bearer token, I am able to call the same API from Swagger and get the expected data back.

I am using `HttpClient` to make the API calls:

> ```
> import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
> ...
>      
> constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient
>             private router: Router) { }
>      
> ... 
> const tokenHeader = new HttpHeaders({ "Authorization": `Bearer ${token}` }); 
> const options = { headers: tokenHeader };  
> return this.httpClient.post<any>(url, postParams, options);
> ```

**error in the console**
[image]

**request:**

[image]

**Preflight request:**

[image: preflight request]

Comment: You have only shared the request headers. Could you share the full request details from the browser?

Comment: There was really no other details from the request... I added the preflight request details if that helps

Comment: Yup, the OPTIONS call. Check my response.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26626522/2501279) can help?

Comment: Hi Guru, my backend application only accepts origin from the angular application...

Comment: What's the `DefaultAuthenticationScheme` specified in the `AddAuthentication` call? Do you specify `[Authorize(AuthenticationScheme = "bearer")]` on your controller or controller method?

Comment: the `DefaultauthenticationScheme` is `JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme`. All I needed to do was to move the `app.UseCors()` before the other `app.Usexx()` methods and it started to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me...
https://stackoverflow.com/a/55764660/10931383

Move the `app.UseCors()` before these:

> ```
> app.UseHttpsRedirection()
> app.UseDefaultFiles()
> app.UseStaticFiles()
> app.UseCookiePolicy()
> ```

Answer (score 0):

it is necessary to activate cors on the backend side so that it authorizes the front to use the apis

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: Hi Souhail, I do have Cors activated on the backend. I am able to call endpoints that do not have the `Authorize` attribute

Comment: Okay that's the cause, good job

Answer (score 0):

`401` is for unauthorized requests. It's the browser that makes an `OPTIONS` call before making the actual request due to the `CORS` policy, but the browser doesn't send the Authorization header on this type of call. As you can see the OPTIONS request doesn't include the token so you need to make sure that your server doesn't respond with 401 to OPTIONS requests.

Comment: thanks Harry... I have been trying to google how to exclude the options calls from authentication but i haven't found anything useful... this is a .net core application. Do you know how do to that?